# sscanf behaves differently all of a sudden

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

So I have an old program(studiomdl from the Half-Life sdk) that's written in C and uses sscanf to parse values out of an ASCII file that contains model data. Now I haven't modified the program in ages, and what I noticed is that somehow it behaves differently now when I compile it in VS2010. Previously this program worked properly and read files blazing fast, however since I recompiled it on my desktop, it's super slow, and somehow seems to corrupt the data I am reading. The only difference since the last compile is that I reinstalled Windows 7 in the meantime.

However, about a year ago, I noticed that for some reason sscanf crashed when reading less fields than there are in a single parsed line. I just added more fields to cover bone weights, because the program was meant to handle only 4 boneweights, but sometimes the 3DS Max SMD exporter writes more than that. Before that, it did not have such problems reading in less values than there were in the SMD.

Can anyone perhaps give a hint as to why I am seeing this altered behavior in sscanf?

The relevant code can be found here:
https://github.com/ValveSoftware/halflife/blob/master/utils/studiomdl/studiomdl.c#L1845

Comment: Don't describe your code, show it (or at least the relevant parts). That will make it much easier to find any problems.

Comment: Because you have updated `sscanf` to Microsoft's `sscanf_s` after being prompted by the compiler? It is not a drop-in replacement, but needs additional arguments for some format specifiers (`%c`, `%s`, `%[]`). Please post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows the problem. Note that it should not matter if there is more data in the string than you ask `sscanf` to scan for, it is ignored, so if that "fixed" the problem, it is more likely that you masked a different problem.

Comment: The relevant code can be found here: https://github.com/ValveSoftware/halflife/blob/master/utils/studiomdl/studiomdl.c#L1845

Comment: Also I didn't update sscanf, I still use the original, albeit deprecated version of it.

Comment: If code worked then, but not now, and with some data but not with other, that is a classic symptom of *undefined behaviour* **somewhere** in the code. Your use of `sscanf` looks OK but examining 3400 lines of code is a bit of an ask. There is even more code than that to look through too, because `s_vertex_t` (the target of the `sscanf`) isn't in this file.